# ¿mostrar con una consulta a las personas que no están registradas?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Hola a todos necesito la lista de las personas que no estan registradas en un fecha determinada, les explico un poco la logica cuando una persona asiste en la base de datos se registra los datos y la fecha,y si falta ese dia simplemente no se registra, estas personas tiene su tabla, necesito que con una consulta saber quienes no han asistido esa fecha

les paso mi consulta donde compruebo si la persona asistió , bueno y  no me sale ningún registro por que no esta registrado ese día

```
select  pa.PACI_Codigo , per.PERSC_Nombre,per.PERSC_ApellidoPaterno, 

con.CONS_FechaAtencion,con.CONS_FechaRegistro,con.CONS_FlagEstado,con.CONS_FlagEstadoAtencion  
from cji_paciente pa
join cji_persona per on per.PERSP_Codigo = pa.PERSP_Codigo
join cji_consulta con on con.PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo
where per.PERSC_NumeroDocIdentidad='42764756'
and con.CONS_FechaRegistro ='2017-04-05'
```

espero su ayuda gracias

Comment: ¿Es Oracle o MySQL? En las etiquetas pones a ambos, lo cual no sería correcto.

Comment: es en mysql , pero pongo otras etiquetas por que si lo han hecho con otras herramientas es el mismo lenguaje SQL y me puedo guiar

Comment: A pesar de utilizar el mismo lenguaje siempre existirán diferencias que pueden ocasionar errores, lo mismo ocurre con SQL Server.

Comment: lo se, se que no sera lo mismo , pero me va servir para guiarme como va lo logica , gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es una consulta que te devuelva las personas que **no** están registradas, lo que debes hacer es usar `where not exists`...

La consulta tendría que ser algo así (no tengo forma de probarla):

```
select pa.PACI_Codigo, per.PERSC_Nombre, per.PERSC_ApellidoPaterno
from cji_paciente pa join cji_persona per on per.PERSP_Codigo = pa.PERSP_Codigo
where per.PERSC_NumeroDocIdentidad='42764756'
  and not exists (select *
                  from cji_consulta
                  where PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo
                    and CONS_FechaRegistro ='2017-04-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fácil:

1. Necesitas `left join` con la tabla de `consultas`, para que te liste todos los pacientes que no existan en consulta.
2. Poner la condición donde `con.[caulqueirCampo] = null`, con esto validas que solo filtre los que no existan en la tabla de consultas, al hacer el `left join` todos los valores de persona que no existan en consulta se mostraran con los campos de consulta en `null`.

Otro punto importante debe quitar del where: `per.PERSC_NumeroDocIdentidad='42764756'`

El código quedaría mas o menos así:

```
select  
  pa.PACI_Codigo 
  ,per.PERSC_Nombre
  ,per.PERSC_ApellidoPaterno
  ,con.CONS_FechaAtencion
  ,con.CONS_FechaRegistro
  ,con.CONS_FlagEstado
  ,con.CONS_FlagEstadoAtencion  
from cji_paciente pa
   join cji_persona per on per.PERSP_Codigo = pa.PERSP_Codigo
   left join cji_consulta con on con.PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo --lef join para que muestre todo de la tabla paciente
where
    con.CONS_FechaRegistro not in ('2017-04-05') -- No se si esto funcione en mySQL, pero algo así
    -- con.CONS_FechaRegistro in ('2017-04-05', null) -- No se si esto funcione en mySQL, pero algo así
    -- or con.CONS_FechaRegistro  = null  --Aquí esta el truco, para que seleccione solo los que no fueron a consulta en esa fecha
```

Este código también debería funcionar:

```
    select  
  pa.PACI_Codigo 
  ,per.PERSC_Nombre
  ,per.PERSC_ApellidoPaterno
  ,con.CONS_FechaAtencion
  ,con.CONS_FechaRegistro
  ,con.CONS_FlagEstado
  ,con.CONS_FlagEstadoAtencion  
from cji_paciente pa
   join cji_persona per on per.PERSP_Codigo = pa.PERSP_Codigo
   left join cji_consulta con on con.PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo --lef join 
   and con.CONS_FechaRegistro = '2017-04-05'
where
    con.CONS_FechaRegistro = null
```

Comment: gracias, pero no funciona y es por que en realidad no existe esa fila , cuando tu pones null significa q existe la fila y el valor es null , en este caso no puede hacer esa comparacion por que no existe la fila

Comment: Así se hace, cuando la fila no existe tiene valor `null`, revisa bien tus inners o la información.

Comment: Quita la sentencia where y valida que información te retorna, después ve quitando los joins para validar que información tienes en realidad, puede que el join que tienes con tabla persona este haciendo que no te regrese información porque no existen los pacientes en la tabla personas... tienes que revisar por partes.

Comment: Otro punto importante, tienes información? en cada tabla individual, estas haciendo la consulta desde la BD directo?

Comment: si revise los inner, cuando utilize tu codigo si me arroja valores pero me trae los que asistieron ese dia osea lo contrario que quiero, si estoy trabajando directo con la base de datos , gracias

Comment: pues mas facil.... XD solo cambia esta parte `con.CONS_FechaRegistro not in ('2017-04-05')`

Comment: Revisa mis comentarios, espero que con eso ya puedas resolver tu consulta :-), gracias por la retroalimentación.  Saludos